# How to implement the chain of pages visited by user similar to the windows folder structure in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation

I don't know what it is called exactly, but what i am trying to find out is how to implement a chain of pages the user visits.

For example: There are two models User and Comment.
Scenario:-
User goes to show action of his page, then he clicks on list of comments he made after which he clicks on a specific comment.

The above should be display below the nav-bar like this:-

> User>Comment>Specific_comment

Now if he clicks on the User he will be taken to his page.

now the display would be like this

> User

Please, give suggestions on where to look.

Comment: It's called a `breadcrumb`. I believe there are some gems. Or, you can roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap with your Rails app it's pretty easy to do here's the documentation https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/breadcrumb/

here's how I used bootstraps breadcrumb in my Rails app

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><%= link_to 'Groups', groups_path, class: "" %></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">New Group</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```